# z-Coordinate and interpolation plugin in QGis

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I've a csv file that includes weather stations locations (x,y,z) and precipitation values. I loaded the file by using add delimited text and then converted it into a point shapefile WS84. By using the interpolation plugin I managed to create the different rainfall zones using pseudocolor and later I extracted the contour. However, as I have z values for elevation I'd like to take this into consideration. The interpolation plugin includes the option to select z-Coordinate to load elevation points but I cannot select it. When I open the plugin without any layer loaded the check box works fine, but when the layer is present is not possible to select the check box. The values of elevation column (z) are in mm.

Am I  missing anything ?

QGIS 1.8.0, interpolation plugin loaded from the repository, running Windows Vista.

---

I believe the answer is that z data must be within the shapefile not as a feature:

"Also note that you can use the z-coordinate for the interpolation. This is the elevation of your data that is stored within the geometry itself and not in an attribute column. This is only possible if your GIS data is in 3 dimensions." in gistutor.com/quantum-gis/20-intermediate-quantum-gis-tutorials/… . So it seems you need to generate "real" 3D-data first, but this is a blank spot for me, sorry. – Bernd V

Comment: Possibly this is a result of how your QGIS instance was built, or the backend you are using. Perhaps you could edit your post to include this information? If you didn't build it yourself, information about exactly which version it is, and where you got it, might be useful.

Comment: no real idea, but a lot of functions in qgis do not work in WGS84, but without pointing out to that.
Maybe project your layer to some metric projection and retry.

Comment: Thanks, I did into pseudo mercator. I don't think it's a projection issue.

Comment: found: "Also note that you can use the z-coordinate for the interpolation.  This is the elevation of your data that is stored **within the geometry itself** and not in an attribute column. This is only possible if your GIS data is in 3 dimensions." in http://www.gistutor.com/quantum-gis/20-intermediate-quantum-gis-tutorials/51-inverse-distance-weighting-idw-interpolation-using-qgis.html . So it seems you need to generate "real" 3D-data first, but this is a blank spot for me, sorry.

Comment: Yes, I followed that tutorial for my data but I overlooked that part, I assumed the contrary! It appears that I need a real 3D data. Thanks for pointing it out:)

Comment: @Bernd V. please put the comment as answer so I can close the question. Txs

Comment: couldn't you take that comment and include that into an own answer to yourself, adding some guidelines about creating 3D-geometries, so ppl will not only have the reason why it didn't work, but also how to get it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill z-values in rainfall points, using specific function in Qgis:

1. In Toolbox of Processing find by "Set Z-Value"
2. Use IDW Interpolation to select Z-Values
3. Create the raster with representation of rainfall